# Erlang Heroku RabbitMQ

Tags: heroku, erlang, rabbitmq

i run in terminal command

heroku config:get RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_RX_URL --app app1

give me a string

amqp://Ajwj23X3:nsi3sC@leaping-charlock-1.bigwig.lshift.net:18372/Hbau2x3d

I copy login,password,url,port to erlang code

```
-record(amqp_params_network, {username           = <<"Ajwj23X3">>,
                              password           = <<"nsi3sC">>,
                              virtual_host       = <<"/">>,
                              host               = "leaping-charlock-1.bigwig.lshift.net",
                              port               = 18372,
                              channel_max        = 0,
                              frame_max          = 0,
                              heartbeat          = 0,
                              connection_timeout = infinity,
                              ssl_options        = none,
                              auth_mechanisms    =
                              [fun amqp_auth_mechanisms:plain/3,
                                fun amqp_auth_mechanisms:amqplain/3],
                              client_properties  = [],
                              socket_options     = []}).
```

But when i run program and connection false

How correctly  write amqp_params_network in erlang for heroku rabbitqm?

Comment: There is an extra space at the end of your `host` setting.

Comment: its old edit error, host  not work             = "leaping-charlock-1.bigwig.lshift.net"

Comment: I find the BIGWIG documentation to be rather bad but I would assume that `Hbau2x3d` is your vhost.

Answer (score 0):

`-record` is the definition of the record type, and the values contained there are just defaults.  It would be rather unusual to hard-code connection parameters as defaults for the record, even more so when the record definition is provided by an external library.

Instead, construct a record instance with the required data:

```
Params = #amqp_params_network{username = <<"Ajwj23X3">>,
                              password = <<"nsi3sC">>,
                              host     = "leaping-charlock-1.bigwig.lshift.net",
                              port     = 18372},
```

and use that instance when connecting:

```
{ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(Params),
```